# Custom sounds for local notification in iphone, but using the build in sounds

Tags: notifications, local, audio

I am setting up a local notification and I am using:

```
// other code to setup myNotifyAlarm (omitted)
myNotifyAlarm.soundName = @"Glass.aiff";
[app scheduleLocalNotification:myNotifyAlarm];
```

(code found in many sites as an example on how to set a local notif.)

But I get the sound set in the Settings->Sounds->Text-Tone not Glass.aiff.
I tried to replace the @"Glass.aiff" with the .caf sounds (from http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices), no luck there either.

I don't want to include "my own" sounds, the iPhone (and other iDevices) have a lot of build in sounds that I could use. The question is how?
(I want to give the user an option to choose a different sound for each notification alert (my app has 4 "types"), so I need a way to change the sound... something like a personalized ring-tone for notifications)